# option missing to add custom API for Azure Mobile services from Visual studio 2013

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-mobile-services

In the server explorer of VS 2013, when I expand 'Windows Azure->Mobile services->my Mobile service', I see the tables in my Mobile services. I can code its get/insert/delete operations. However when I right click to add Custom API, I don't see the option 'Create Custom API'
Am I missing any package/add-on/external tool or some such thing?

note: my service is having 'Node.js' backend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update to [Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42307) to be able to work with custom API's. Once updated, you should be able to see your custom APIs appear under your mobile service, and be able to right-click and add new custom APIs.